# Change WizardSmallBitmapImage in Inno Setup Uninstaller

Tags: windows, inno-setup

In installer, you can easily change the small bitmap in wizard's top right corner using this code:

```
[Setup]
WizardSmallImageFile=gfx\bitmap.bmp
```

Hovewer, how to change that same bitmap in uninstaller's wizard's top right corner?
There doesn't seem to be any parameter for this.

I think one of the solution is to let the installer extract the required bitmap into the `{app}` and then use this code:

```
procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm;
var bitmap : string;
begin
    bitmap := ExpandConstant('{app}\uninst.bmp');
    uninstallProgressForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(bitmap);
end;
```

However, I don't want to have that satelite bitmap hanging in my `{app}`, I want it to be compiled into the uninstaller. Is it possible to somehow compile that bitmap into the uninstaller? Or is there some other way how to change that bitmap in the uninstaller's wizard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to compile additional files into the uninstaller.

Comment: And is there some hidden parameter which would allow me to set the uninstaller's WizardSmallImageFile? Is there even any reason why the uninstaller is not using the same image as the installer?

Comment: I've added it [here](http://innosetup.uservoice.com/forums/33177-inno-setup-feature-request/suggestions/1016549-uninstall-set-wizardsmallbitmapimage-in-uninstall) as a feature request, so vote if you also miss this feature.